# How to Install Zipline on Google Colab

Tags: installation, zipline, google-colaboratory

```
!apt-get install libatlas-base-dev python-dev gfortran pkg-config libfreetype6-dev hdf5-tools

!pip install zipline

!pip install zipline ingest

!pip uninstall pandas
!pip install --upgrade pandas==0.23.0

%load_ext zipline
```

I have following issue:

> ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

[image: enter image description here][1]

after adding cuperto suggested (!pip install pandas==0.22.0),
I got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWHWm.jpg)

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to run Zipline on Google Colab, I ran into the exact same problem.

I believe the problem comes from the fact that zipline 1.4.1 has requirement pandas<=0.22,>=0.18.1

So I installed an older version of pandas and it worked:

```
!pip install pandas==0.22.0
```

Comment: I checked the Answer BUT still gets error:      ERROR: google-colab 1.0.0 has requirement pandas~=1.1.0; python_version >= "3.0", but you'll have pandas 0.22.0 which is incompatible.